# Бабушка и дедушка одним словом?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Отца и мать можно назвать "родители", а как можно назвать бабушку и дедушку одним словом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прародитель — это родитель отца и матери, как по отцовской линии, так и по материнской (начиная от третьего поколения). Прародители являются родственниками второй степени и имеют 25% генетического совпадения с внуками.

(Из Википедии: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)

> Взаимоотношения поколений можно рассматривать в различных аспектах:
>   как исторически и культурно изменчивое явление; как психологическое
>   наследование; как личные отношения прародителей (бабушек/дедушек) и их
>   детей и внуков.

(http://www.semya-rastet.ru/razd/praroditeli_v_sisteme_semejjnykh_otnoshenijj/)